# Getting urname / password from http url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http, authentication

Is it possible to get the username / password in asp.net (mvc3) from a http url where it is formated like this?

http://user:password@example.com/path

or is it only possible with the ftp protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The username and password in your example are using HTTP Basic Authentication - they aren't part of the URL but rather included in the header information. You can access this info in ASP.NET, see this article: [Basic Authentication with Asp.Net WebAPI](http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/basic-authentication-with-asp-net-webapi/)

```
public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext) {
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization == null){
            // No Header Auth Info
            actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        } else {
            // Get the auth token
            string authToken = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
            // Decode the token from BASE64
            string decodedToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authToken));

            // Extract username and password from decoded token
            string username = decodedToken.Substring(0, decodedToken.IndexOf(":"));
            string password = decodedToken.Substring(decodedToken.IndexOf(":") + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this may be a stupid question. but when does the OnActionExecuting fire?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting(v=vs.98).aspx - it is called by every Action method in your Controller class. My ASP.NET knowledge is a bit dated beyond that though, I haven't used it in quite a while...